# Spring Batch Add Custom Fields

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I've never used Spring Batch before but it seems like a viable option for what I am attempting to accomplish. I have about 15 CSV files for 10 institutions that I need to process nightly. I am stashing the CSV into staging tables in an Oracle database.

The CSV File may look something like this.

```
DEPARTMENT_ID,DEPARTMENT_NAME,DEPARTMENT_CODE
100,Computer Science & Engineering,C5321
101,Math,M333
...
```

However when I process the row and add it to the database I need to fill in an institution id which would be determined based on the folder being processed at that time.

The database table would like like this

```
INSTITUTION_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID,DEPARTMENT_NAME,DEPARTMENT_CODE
1100,100,Computer Science & Engineering,C5321
```

There is also validation that needs to be done on each row in the CSV files as well. Is that something Spring Batch can handle as well?

I've seen reference to CustomItemReader and CustomItemWriter but not sure if that is what I need. The examples I've seen seem basic just dumping a CSV exactly as it is into a matching table.

Comment: That is what an `ItemProcessor` is for.

Comment: First hit when searching spring batch examples is this page https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples where there are lot of examples, also advanced once. Try researching Football Job example to get better understanding of spring batch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , all the task that you have reported can be done by spring batch -

For the Reader you may use - multi Resource Item Reader with your wild card name matching your - file names .

To validate the rows from file you can use item processor and handle the validation.

And for your case you need not use the custom item writer - you can configure the item writer as DB item writer in your XML file.

I suggest you to use the XML based approach for Spring batch implementation.

The XML will be used to configure all the architecture of your batch - as in

```
job -- step -- chunk -- reader -- processor -- writer
```

and to track errors and exceptions you can implement listeners at each stage.

```
 -- step Execution Listener
```

-- Item Reader Listener 
 -- Item Processor Listener 
 -- Item Writer Listener